# Building in the built-in declarations

Tags: c#, singleton, reflection, rubberduck

In order for [**Rubberduck**](http://www.rubberduck-vba.com) to be able to "recognize" the built-in VBA functions, procedures and objects, I added yet another constructor parameter to my `Declaration` class:

```
public Declaration(QualifiedMemberName qualifiedName, string parentScope,
    string identifierName, string asTypeName, bool isSelfAssigned, bool isWithEvents,
    Accessibility accessibility, DeclarationType declarationType, ParserRuleContext context, Selection selection, bool isBuiltIn = false)
{
    _qualifiedName = qualifiedName;
    _parentScope = parentScope;
    _identifierName = identifierName;
    _asTypeName = asTypeName;
    _isSelfAssigned = isSelfAssigned;
    _isWithEvents = isWithEvents;
    _accessibility = accessibility;
    _declarationType = declarationType;
    _selection = selection;
    _context = context;
    _isBuiltIn = isBuiltIn;
}
```

That constructor is becoming a real mess, but now I can tell built-in declarations from the rest - this way I can know if the user is trying to rename the `MsgBox` function, and forbid it instead of happily letting the user break their code; as a bonus I can now also map identifier usages to these declarations, so the user can right-click any `MsgBox` function call, and I can show them everywhere they're using it in their VBA project.

So I proceeded to implement a little helper class that would give me an `IEnumerable<Declaration>` containing everything the [VBA Standard Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200283.aspx) exposes.

Because I'm only ever going to need to instantiate these declarations once, I decided to make it a `static` class, exposing nothing but a `Declarations` property getter.

At first I had a `#region` for each predefined module and class, and another for the predefined enums.. but I don't like `#region`, so I decided to use private nested types instead, and to define the `Declaration` instances as public static fields, so that I could easily use reflection to fetch all instances from all nested types, like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines <see cref="Declaration"/> objects for the standard library.
/// </summary>
internal static class VbaStandardLib
{
    private static readonly QualifiedModuleName EmptyModuleName = new QualifiedModuleName();

    private static IEnumerable<Declaration> StandardLibDeclarations;

    public static IEnumerable<Declaration> Declarations
    {
        get
        {
            return StandardLibDeclarations ??
                   (StandardLibDeclarations = typeof (VbaStandardLib).GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                       .SelectMany(t => t.GetFields().Select(f => (Declaration) f.GetValue(null))));
        }
    }
```

---

Here are a few of these nested types, just to illustrate what they look like:

```
private class VbaLib
{
    public static Declaration Vba = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "VBA"), "VBA", "VBA", "VBA", true, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Project, null, Selection.Home, true);

    public static Declaration FormShowConstants = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "FormShowConstants"), "VBA", "FormShowConstants", "FormShowConstants", false, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Enumeration, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration VbModal = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "vbModal"), "VBA", "vbModal", "FormShowConstants", true, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.EnumerationMember, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration VbModeless = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "vbModeless"), "VBA", "vbModeless", "FormShowConstants", true, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.EnumerationMember, null, Selection.Home, true);

    public static Declaration VbAppWinStyle = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "VbAppWinStyle"), "VBA", "VbAppWinStyle", "VbAppWinStyle", false, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Enumeration, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration VbHide = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "vbHide"), "VBA", "vbHide", "VbAppWinStyle", true, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.EnumerationMember, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration VbMaximizedFocus = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "vbMaximizedFocus"), "VBA", "vbMaximizedFocus", "VbAppWinStyle", true, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.EnumerationMember, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration VbMinimizedFocus = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "vbMinimizedFocus"), "VBA", "vbMinimizedFocus", "VbAppWinStyle", true, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.EnumerationMember, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration VbMinimizedNoFocus = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "vbMinimizedNoFocus"), "VBA", "vbMinimizedNoFocus", "VbAppWinStyle", true, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.EnumerationMember, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration VbNormalFocus = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "vbNormalFocus"), "VBA", "vbNormalFocus", "VbAppWinStyle", true, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.EnumerationMember, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration VbNormalNoFocus = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "vbNormalNoFocus"), "VBA", "vbNormalNoFocus", "VbAppWinStyle", true, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.EnumerationMember, null, Selection.Home, true);
    ...
```

I've regrouped the members so as to mirror the structure of the `VBA` standard library, so the declarations contained in the `VBA.Information` module are defined in the `InformationModule` class:

```
private class InformationModule
{
    public static Declaration Information = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "Information"), "VBA", "Information", "Information", false, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Module, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration Err = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "Err"), "VBA.Information", "Err", "ErrObject", false, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Function, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration IMEStatus = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "IMEStatus"), "VBA.Information", "IMEStatus", "vbIMEStatus", false, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Function, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration IsArray = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "IsArray"), "VBA.Information", "IsArray", "Boolean", false, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Function, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration IsDate = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "IsDate"), "VBA.Information", "IsDate", "Boolean", false, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Function, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration IsEmpty = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "IsEmpty"), "VBA.Information", "IsEmpty", "Boolean", false, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Function, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration IsError = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "IsError"), "VBA.Information", "IsError", "Boolean", false, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Function, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration IsMissing = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "IsMissing"), "VBA.Information", "IsMissing", "Boolean", false, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Function, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration IsNull = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "IsNull"), "VBA.Information", "IsNull", "Boolean", false, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Function, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration IsNumeric = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "IsNumeric"), "VBA.Information", "IsNumeric", "Boolean", false, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Function, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration IsObject = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "IsObject"), "VBA.Information", "IsObject", "Boolean", false, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Function, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration QBColor = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "QBColor"), "VBA.Information", "QBColor", "Long", false, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Function, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration RGB = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "RGB"), "VBA.Information", "RGB", "Long", false, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Function, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration TypeName = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "TypeName"), "VBA.Information", "TypeName", "String", false, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Function, null, Selection.Home, true);
    public static Declaration VarType = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "VarType"), "VBA.Information", "vbVarType", "Boolean", false, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Function, null, Selection.Home, true);
}
```

There are quite a few more, listing them here would be irrelevant.

Should I restructure this? This code isn't really going to be maintained, unless the `VBA` standard library suddenly earns new members... on the other hand, I might eventually decide to implement similar classes for commonly referenced VBA libraries, such as `Scripting` and `ADODB` - any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I notice that there's a repeating pattern in all of your declarations...

The second parameter in `QualifiedMemberName` is always the same as the third parameter `identifierName`.

I'm assuming that `QualifiedMemberName` has a property for member/identifier so why not recycle that?

I think [Heslacher's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/88111/22816) is the way to go. However,  you could make life slightly easier for yourself by just creating a `BuiltInMember` class:

```
public class BuiltInMember : Declaration
{
    public BuiltInMemember (
            QualifiedMemberName qualifiedName, 
            string parentScope,
            string asTypeName,
            bool isSelfAssigned, 
            bool isWithEvents, 
            DeclarationType declarationType) 
        : base (
            qualifiedName, 
            parentScope, 
            qualifiedName.MemberName, 
            asTypeName, 
            isSelfAssigned, 
            isWithEvents,
            Accessibility.Global, 
            declarationType, 
            null, 
            Selection.Home, 
            true)
    {

    }
}
```

That gets you down to 6 constructor arguments in one step :)

Answer (score 4):

More than 3 input parameters for a method is considered to be a code smell. One could say ok, I have 4 parameters but I can't help it, but **11** input parameters are way too many.

Problems I see with this type of object (`Declaration`) is, that the code gets error prone and prone to use a lot of copy and paste.

Instead of using a `class` you should consider to extract the properties and methods to an interface.
Then you should extract the different types of `Declaration`'s by the meaning of the `string asTypeName` parameter to different classes which implements this interface.

Example:

Instead of

```
public static Declaration IsNull = new Declaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "IsNull"), "VBA.Information", "IsNull", "Boolean", false, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Function, null, Selection.Home, true);
```

you could use

```
public static IDeclaration IsNull = new BooleanDeclaration(new QualifiedMemberName(EmptyModuleName, "IsNull"), "VBA.Information", "IsNull",  false, false, Accessibility.Global, DeclarationType.Function, null, Selection.Home, true);
```

where `BooleanDeclaration` would look like

```
Public class BooleanDeclaration : IDeclaration
{
    public BooleanDeclaration(QualifiedMemberName qualifiedName, string parentScope,
        string identifierName, bool isSelfAssigned, bool isWithEvents,
        Accessibility accessibility, DeclarationType declarationType, ParserRuleContext context, Selection selection, bool isBuiltIn = false)
    {
        _qualifiedName = qualifiedName;
        _parentScope = parentScope;
        _asTypeName = "Boolean";
        _identifierName = identifierName;
        _isSelfAssigned = isSelfAssigned;
        _isWithEvents = isWithEvents;
        _accessibility = accessibility;
        _declarationType = declarationType;
        _selection = selection;
        _context = context;
        _isBuiltIn = isBuiltIn;
    }
}
```

As you can see the number of constructor parameters are reduced by one. The next to remove would be `isWithEvents` because a `Boolean` declaration won't ever be with events.

This can be done for all the basic types like `Long`, `String` etc.

By adding an overloaded constructor without the `ParserRuleContext` parameter you can reduce the number of parameters further.

Alos the `Selection` seems very often to be `Selection.Home` which should be reflected in another (or the same)  overloaded constructor.